# Retrieve projection inside .map() GEE

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, reducers, .map

When using a reducing function such as `.reduceRegion()`, a provided projection is necessary.
This projection has to be provided as  CRS String, and crsTransform List. Both are optainable with :

```
var proj = Im.projection().getInfo()
var crs = proj.crs
var transform = proj.transform
```

[image]

yet the Funktion `.getInfo()` is not usable inside `.map()`, due to its correspondence with the Javascript Interface of Google Earth Engine.

To call the projection with the designated `ee.Projection()` functions is not possible, due to the expectations of .reduceRegions()

```
var proj = Im.projection()
var crs = proj.crs()
var transform = proj.transform()
```

[image]

how can a projection Inside the `.map()` function be retrieved for usage inside `.reduceRegion()`?

```
var min = Im.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.min(),
  crs:crs,
  crsTransform:transform,
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to specify `crsTransform` if use the same transform as given in the projection you passed to `crs`. Furthermore, if you don't set a different crs than supplied by the image you are mapping over, you don't need to specifically define a crs at all. In this case the crs will be taken from the Image you are calling `reduceRegion()` on. But in case you want to take the projection from a different image this should work just fine in a `.map` call:

```
// Different Image from which you take the projection    
var proj = Im2.projection()

var min = Im.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.min(),
  crs: proj
})
```